# MongoDB: How Find the document where their name starts with “S” and “R”?

Tags: database, mongodb, find

I use this manually `db.employees.find({Name: /^S/});`  and  `db.employees.find({Name: /^R/});`  to find the starts letter of "S" and "R",

is their any way to use the two starts letter in one function?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `|` pipe sign to put or condition in regex,

```
db.employees.find({
  Name: /^S|^R/
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5DjKEtjlCph)